# Alternative to Visitor Pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

A known problem with Visitor Pattern is that is doesn't scale well with a rich hierarchy of classes ( Even if you don't add classes often).

When you combine visitor pattern with command pattern hell gates opens. Your visitor interface now has to support all the types of your hierarchy, which might not be desired.

For example, you might want to divide your commands into categories:

```
class CarCommands
{
protected:
        enum TypeOfCommands : uint8_t
        {
                RadioCommands,
                EngineCommands,
                WindowsCommands,

                MaxCarCommands
        };

        uint8_t cmd_type;
};
```

From there, you write your supreclasses:

```
class RadioCmd : CarCommands
{
public:
    RadioCmd() : CarCommands(RadioCommands)
    {}

    // Other radio-specific methods
    ...
    // Other radio-specific data members
    ...
protected:
    enum TypeOfRadioCmd : uint8_t
    {
        Radio_ON,
        Radio_OFF,

        MaxRadioType
    };

    uint8_t radio_type;
};

class EngineCmd : CarCommands
{
pubilc:
    EngineCmd() : CarCommands(EngineCommands)
    {}
protected:
    enum TypeOfEngineCmd : uint8_t
    {
        Engine_Start,
        Engine_Accelerate,
        Engine_Stop,

        MaxEngineType
    };

    uint8_t engine_type;
};
```

It feels natural to have a handler for each category. If I would want to process Engine-related commands, my `EngineCommandHandler` should not know about other types of `CarCommands`. Thus, if I decide to add another engine command, I would only have to modify the `EngineCommandHandler` in order to support it. At the same time, a `CarCommandHandler` should be able to process correctly a `AccelerateEngine` command.

Is there an alternative for *visitor pattern* that scales with a large class hierarchy?
Given the problem, is there another design-pattern that applies better than *visitor pattern* ?

Comment: IMHO, engine, radio, etc made up the car. Engine has its own set of commands (which can scale later too), Radio has its own set of commands. Each component only knows what it supports. Each component should implement vector getCommands() function and should return what is supports. Car has HAS-A relation with  components and it should call getCommands of all the components to to make up a list of supported commands by the car. This will enable flexibility to each component.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: @рüффп I agree! I didn't know about the site from the beginning.